# Guides snapping in wrong location after stage drag

Tags: konvajs

I followed [the guide on making snapping rulers](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Objects_Snapping.html), but I have additional functionality.
The issue is that after dragging stage, the rules appear in the wrong location.

I have tried looking, but can't find anything to use for e.g. something like an offset.
Here's a JSfiddle. It is 100% identical to the example, except `stage` has `draggable: true` *(and moved CSS/JS out of HTML)*.

https://jsfiddle.net/jyupeqx9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are moving a stage and all positions of inner shapes (like rectangles and guid lines) are relative to the stage, you have to adjust position calculations.

To do that you can just update `getClientRect` function usage:

```js
node.getClientRect({ relativeTo: stage});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/rbahewmu/